# When I add more than one states to an <item> in a state-list drawable, it stops working. Why?

Tags: android, android-drawable, xml-drawable, statelistdrawable, statelist

**What I want:**

An ImageView with a transparent background. When it is clicked, its background should turn blue, and should remain blue until something else is clicked. I am using state-list drawable for it.

**What is happening:**

The code is given as follows. **The problem is that the background does turn blue, but it does not remain blue.** So I thought it is because `android:state_pressed` just represents the moment when the widget is *being* clicked. So I also added `android:state_selected="true"` to `button_state_list_drawable.xml` right after `android:state_pressed="true"`. **What happened then is that the background stopped turning blue even when the imageview is *being* clicked.**

How do I fix this?

`ImageView` defined in XML like this:

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_imageView"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_photo"
        android:background="@drawable/button_state_list_drawable"
        android:clickable="true" />
```

The `button_state_list_drawable.xml` is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed_state_drawable"
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:state_selected="true" />

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_enabled_state_drawable" />

</selector>
```

The `button_pressed_state_drawable.xml` is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval" >

    <size android:width="50dp"
        android:height="50dp" />

    <padding android:left="25dp"
        android:right="25dp"
        android:top="25dp"
        android:bottom="25dp" />

    <stroke android:color="#fff"
        android:width="1dp" />

    <solid android:color="#1aafd0" />

</shape>
```

The `button_enabled_state_drawable.xml` is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval" >

    <size android:width="50dp"
        android:height="50dp" />

    <padding android:left="25dp"
        android:right="25dp"
        android:top="25dp"
        android:bottom="25dp" />

    <stroke android:color="#fff"
        android:width="1dp" />

    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />

</shape>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the remaining [`button states`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html) (`focused`, `selected` etc), maybe you pass a state and the color falls back to the default one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently had this problem, and this is what I did.

In your button_state_list_drawable.xml, add this somewhere *before* you default state item:

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed_state_drawable"
        android:state_selected="true"
        android:state_pressed="false" />
```

Also remove `android:state_selected="true"` from your `state_pressed` item.

Then in the beginning of your click listener for the `ImageView`, write

```
yourImageView.setSelected(true);
```

This had solved my problem. Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

I don´t know if this is the solution, but I have to show some code. You haven´t added a default state to your selector and I can´t see your selected state (you wrote it in yur question, but you haven´t posted it). It must be something like this:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >


   <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_enabled_state_drawable"
        android:state_enabled="true" />

   <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed_state_drawable"
        android:state_pressed="true" />

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/your_selected_state_drawable"
        android:state_selected="true" />

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/your_button_default_drawable"/>

</selector>
```

And I think you have to add programmatically the selected state (I´m not sure for this or if it does it automatically)

```
yourImageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
      @Override
  public void onClick(View v){

        if(yourImageView.isSelected()){
            yourImageView.setSelected(false);
          }else{
            yourImageView.setSelected(true);
          }
    }
});
```

Comment: No, I had added it to the same drawable: `<item android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed_state_drawable"
    android:state_pressed="true"  android:state_selected="true" />`. Editing the question to show that and the default state

Comment: ok, but do you set the selected state programmatically like I show above?

Comment: Yeah I am just gonna try that.

Comment: Now I am really confused. What is happening is that when I click it a single time, nothing happens. When I double click it, blue background appears just _momentarily_ - as soon as I let go of the mouse/finger from the second click, the blue background goes away.

Comment: And if I double click, and _hold the second click_, the blue background appears, for as long as I keep the second click pressed. As soon as I lift up my finger/mouse, the blue color goes away

Comment: By the way it is an ImageView, not a Button.

Comment: what you describe ist the pressed state behaviour....ok, edited....can you please post the part where you click on your image?

Comment: I had explored in the past, that the order of a selector is important....try to switch the selected state beofre the pressed state....

Comment: By "part", do you mean code? it is just your code in `onClick()` method, I commented out my code so that I could concentrate on this problem only for the time being.

Comment: yep that´s what I meant. If it is exactly the one I have posted, ok I don´t need to see it, but sometimes four eyes see more than two ;) . Anyway, have you tried to switch the order of the states in your selector? As I suggested, in the past I stumpled over it, that it is important how the states are ordered. Here I think you should switch the pressed and selected state.

Comment: And what´s the selected state of your button at the start of the activity? if it is selected, logically nothing happens if the background is in the selected state. You should set the selected state after initializing your button the wanted state.